# Visual Studio Compile standalone C# file

Tags: visual-studio, c#, compile

I have a c# file, I opened it in VS2010, and I want to compile it now. Is it possible? I know I can compile it using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe, but I do not want this. I want to know if I can compile a standalone C# file from VS2010. 
Thanks.

PS I strongly think that the stackoverflow/superuser search needs to be improved a lot. I hardly seem to be able to find questions. Something tells me that this is the kind of question that must have been asked before, but I can't find out.

Comment: As for your search questions see http://stackoverflow.com/search http://superuser.com/search and [Stack Overflow Search – Now 61% Less Crappy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)

Comment: I think visual 6 was the last to let you do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio is orientated around projects, so you'd need to add your cs file to a new (empty) project, before you can compile it through Visual Studio.

Comment: Thats sad. I don't like that folder structure etc, but okay, will have to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While this really doesn't answer your question, may I recommend taking a look at [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)? It does so much more than just execute LINQ - I use it to rapidly test/demo code as I can compile it immediately and see the results. The work the author did with the .Dump() extension method is super helpful as well.

[image]